# Code changes to build z3 on Solaris

Tags: z3

I have need to get z3 building on Solaris 8.  I took a look at the file scoped_timer.cpp, which is the only place that uses -D_LINUX_, and figure I can get the right code in there for Solaris, guarding it with -D_SOLARIS_.  Also, src/util/hwf.cpp would need to be changed to provide definitions of fma() and nearbyint(), which aren't defined on Solaris 8.  That can be done too, by defining fma(x, y, z) to be x*y + z, but then there would be two roundings instead of one, which is required by IEEE 754.  Would this pose a problem for the purposes of z3?  I would also need to change mk_util.py to set up compile and link options for Solaris.  This also seems rather feasible as we are using g++ on Solaris, so the compile options would be similar.  The link options probably would require additional libraries.  I am willing to do some of the legwork, but I may need help along the way.  Would anyone be willing to work with me, and would this be an welcome addition?

Comment: What's your hardware?  x86 or SPARC?  Older hardware tends not to have true FMA instructions - SPARC got it in 2007, x86 not until 2011 for AMD and 2013 for Intel.  Also, if you can get a copy of Solaris Studio for your hardware.  Look under the install directory's .../prod/lib directory and find all the `math.il` files.  Those files are the assembly instructions for inlined math routines.  There's a `nearbyint()` implementation in the x86 install I have of Solaris Studio 12.3.

Comment: I ran into the following when I tried to compile Z3 on OpenBSD/SPARC: as of some older build, the memory manager may mistakenly believe that since you are not using AMD64, your processor is 32 bits and therefore the memory allocator can 4-byte align everything. On SPARC64 this won't be the case and 8-byte alignment is required; be careful.

Comment: We are using SPARC Solaris 8 to build 32 bit applications.  I tired building with Sun Studio 11 as version 12 is not supported on Solaris, but had a lot of compiler error.  I do have access to a Solaris 10 box and Sun Studio 12 so I can try with that, but I am reluctant to do so as some of our users are still son Solaris 8.

Answer (score 0):

> would this be an welcome addition?

I guess we can take a pull request when it is ready (and not obscuring other settings) and there are at least two users for this. 
The usual conditions apply for taking pull requests https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki/Contribution-Guidelines. 
Of course you can have your own forks without merging changes back.

The other issue may be that the endianness on your machines and the 
constraints on memory alignment may expose further portability problems. 
You should be able to find issues by running the regression tests under z3test repository (as well as the unit tests). We recently fixed some endianness related problems for ARM/PowerPC.

Comment: OK, will keep this in mind.  Right now I just high jacked the FreeBSD configuration, but I will clean things up so that there is a specific config/code changes for Solaris.

Comment: I have a stack trace of what is either an alignment of endianess issue, but I think I am going to have to make a new post as the stack trace is took long for a comment.